# Modular Exponentiation overflow

Tags: java, recursion, overflow

```
public class Solution {
    public int pow(int A,int B,int d)
{
    if(A<0){ A=A+d;}
    if (B==0)
    {
        if(A==0){return 0;}
        return 1;
    }
    else if(B%2==0)
    {
        int y=pow(A,B/2,d);
        return (y*y)%d;
    }
    else
    {
        return (A%d*pow(A,B-1,d))%d;
    }
}
```

}

My code overflows for,
A : 71045970
B : 41535484
d : 64735492

my code gives o/p: -17412928
expected o/p : 20805472
Where it goes wrong?

can someone modify my code?

Comment: `int` holds up to 32 bits of information ~ -2kkk ... 2kkk, you are squaring `y` in `(y*y)%d`, where `y` can easily be over 1kk.

Comment: ok, how I modify it ?

Comment: That depends on your input data restrictions, if they can't be more than `int`, then simply replace all `int`s in your code with `long`s, otherwise you will have to use `BigInteger`.

Comment: I don't know how to use biginteger in my code. can you please modify my code?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
public int Mod(int a, int b, int c) {
    if(b==0){
        if(a==0) return 0;
        else
        return 1;
    }
    else if(b%2==0){
        long y=Mod(a,b/2,c);

        return (int)(((long)(y*y))%(long)c);
    }else{
        int k=a%c;
        if(k<0){
            k+=c;
        }
        return (int)(((long)((long)k * (long)Mod(a,b-1,c)))%(long)c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BigInteger` as a [modPow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) method that does this for you trivially.

Not giving your expected result but giving a different result:

```
public int pow(int a, int b, int mod) {
    if (a < 0) {
        a = a + mod;
    }
    if (b == 0) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    } else if (b % 2 == 0) {
        int y = pow(a, b / 2, mod);
        return (y * y) % mod;
    } else {
        return (a % mod * pow(a, b - 1, mod)) % mod;
    }
}

public int bigPow(int a, int b, int mod) {
    return BigInteger.valueOf(a).modPow(BigInteger.valueOf(a), BigInteger.valueOf(mod)).intValue();
}

private void test(int a, int b, int mod) {
    System.out.println("Old - modPow(" + a + "," + b + "," + mod + ") = " + pow(a, b, mod));
    System.out.println("New - modPow(" + a + "," + b + "," + mod + ") = " + bigPow(a, b, mod));
}

public void test() {
    test(71045970, 41535484, 64735492);
}
```

prints

```
Old - modPow(71045970,41535484,64735492) = -17412928
New - modPow(71045970,41535484,64735492) = 44382800
```

In case you actually aren't looking for `modPow` (which now looks likely) here's a rough attemt at duplicating youyr aalgorithm using `BigInteger`.

```
public BigInteger bigPow(BigInteger a, BigInteger b, BigInteger mod) {
    if (a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
        a = a.add(mod);
    }
    if (b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
        if (a.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
            return BigInteger.ZERO;
        }
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    } else if (!b.testBit(0)) {
        BigInteger y = bigPow(a, b.shiftRight(1), mod);
        return y.multiply(y).mod(mod);
    } else {
        return a.mod(mod).multiply(bigPow(a, b.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), mod));
    }
}
```

Now gives the expected answer.

```
Old - modPow(71045970,41535484,64735492) = -17412928
New - modPow(71045970,41535484,64735492) = 20805472
```

Comment: I don't know how to use biginteger in my code. can you please modify my code?

Comment: if I try to call this function with this statement,  p.bigPow(new BigInteger(71045970),new BigInteger(41535484),new BigInteger(64735492));  , I got BigInteger(long) constructor not visible error, how to call?

Comment: @S-N - Use Big integer.value of(int);